# How to wait for a specific result in an function while running other functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I want to run some code while waiting for another response?

Example:

```
var obj = {};

await pre(obj);
await first(obj);
await second(obj);
await third(obj);

await function pre(obj) {self.something = "something";}
await function first(obj){...something...}
await function second(obj){...something...}
await function third(obj){...Do something with obj...}
```

What I can't figure out is, how do I run pre() and do its time-consuming objective, while running first() and second() and third() but third will run when pre has finished?

Comment: it's `async function pre()...` not `await function pre()...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run all of your intermediary steps in parallel before running `third`:

```
var obj = {};

await Promise.all([ pre(obj), first(obj), second(obj)]);
await third(obj);
```

If I'm understanding your question correctly, at by the time the `Promise.all` has finished, `obj` will contain the mutations of running `pre`, `first`, and `second`.

Be careful about error handling as well as nondeterministic access to the `obj` object.

Answer (score 0):

> What I can't figure out is, how do I run pre() and do its time-consuming objective, while running first() and second() and third() but third will run when pre has finished?

Based on this question, it is my understanding that you want to:

1. Run `pre`, `first` and `second` simultaneously
2. Once `pre` has finished executing, then run `third`

If this is the case then the following code will do that :

```
var obj = {test: "Test"};

async function pre(obj) {console.log(`${pre.name} :`, obj); return obj;}
async function first(obj)  {console.log(`${first.name} :`, obj)}
async function second(obj) {console.log(`${second.name} :`, obj)}
async function third(obj)  {console.log(`${third.name} :`, obj)}

Promise.all([first(obj), second(obj), pre(obj).then(third)]);
```

The `Promise.all()` function takes an array of functions that return a promise and executes them in parallel.  Notice the `pre(obj).then(third)`.  This will execute the `pre` function and upon completion will execute the `third` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {};

async function pre(obj) {self.something = "something";}
async function first(obj){...something...}
async function second(obj){...something...}
async function third(obj){...Do something with obj...}

// use array destructuring to get the responses after promises resolve
const [ preResponse, firstResponse, secondResponse ] = await Promise.all([
  pre(obj),
  first(obj),
  second(obj)
]);
const thirdResponse = await third(obj);
```